# Issue with %g precision

Tags: c++, c

When I used `printf("%.6g\n",36.666666662);`, i expected the output `36.666667`. But the actual output is `36.6667`

What is wrong with the format I have given?  My aim is to have 6 decimal digits

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> For a, A, e, E, f and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed **after** the decimal point.
>
> For g and G specifiers: This is the maximum number of significant digits to be printed.

If you use `f` instead of `g` then it will work as you expected.

---

**Example code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%.6g\n", 36.666666662);
    printf("%.6f\n", 36.666666662);
    return 0;
}
```

**Result**

```
36.6667
36.666667
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/4ULNFl).